# javascript Objects assignment node js

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

I am new to JavaScript and going through some of objects example, can some please explain below code...

```js
const car = {type:"Fiat", model:"500", color:"white"};
const {type} = car;
console.log(type)
```

On running the above code in node terminal I am getting undefined with each output.

[image]

I have 2 questions with above code:

1. how does the assignment works here in `const {type} = car;`
2. Why is 'undefined' coming up in each of the output.

Comment: I guess it is the returned value from the expression.

Comment: 2. when the executed statement does not return any value then it is printed undefined in browser console

Comment: 1. [Destructing assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment?retiredLocale=pl) 2. `undefined` is the result of the statement (statements always yield `undefined`)

Comment: `const {type} = car;` means if key specified inside the curly braces of left side exists in the car object then value is of the specified key is assigned to left side variable that is written inside curly braces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. The assignment there is known as Destructuring in Javascript.**

> The destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from objects, into distinct variables

The destructuring assignment uses similar syntax of the object, but on the left-hand side of the assignment to define what values to unpack from the sourced variable.

In your case:

```js
const car = {type:"Fiat", model:"500", color:"white"};
const { type, model } = car;
// is equivalent to:
// const type = car.type;
// const model = car.model;
```

You can read more about Destructuring on the official MDN docs: [MDN: Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

**2. The 'undefined' coming up in each of the output.**

In most javascript console, when you execute a statement or expression it prints the output/return value of the statement or expression. This is a way for the console to indicate that the statement was executed

But if it doesn't return a specific value, the console often displays "undefined" as the result. However, not all statements or expressions will return "undefined".

Answer (score 1):

2.)  Undefined is returned when making variable declarations - this includes when doing shorthand assignment declarations.

```
const car = {type: "Fiat"}
let car2 = {type: "Priaz"}
```

When doing only assignment without declaration you'll see the value is returned.

```
car = {type: "Fiat", model: "500"}
car2 = {type: "Priaz", model: "XW50"}
```